# how to make a conditional loop and a divison by zero is invalid

Tags: python, if-statement

How to make a conditional loop and ("Divison by zero is invalid")
could not find an answer that works I searched for the past day or so

[: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfcFo.png][1]

Comment: `if numberout:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is highly recommended to post text information like code, logs and errors as text not images. It will help other users to find and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `while` loop:

```
print("Welcome to the amazing calculator!\n\n")

loop = True

while(loop): 
    print("--------------------------------------------")

    one = float(input("Enter the first number:"))
    two = float(input("And now the second one:"))

    print("Choose what you want to do with those two numbers: \n")
    print("Add -> '+'\n Substract -> '-'\n Multiply -> '*'\n # And so on...\n")


    sign = input("So which action do you need? ")


    # Now, here you check all conditions etc. I'm not writing this for you ;)

    # In order to use the MATCH keyword you need at least python 3.10
    match sign:
        case "/": 
            if two == 0:
                print("You cannot divide by ZERO!")
            else:
                print(f"Result of division: {one / two}")

        case "+":
            print("And so on...")
    

    # If you don't have python 3.10 installed, just use if/else like you did in your code
    if sign == "/": 
            if two == 0:
                print("You cannot divide by ZERO!")
            else:
                print(f"Result of division: {one / two}")

    # And when user wants to exit the program
    else:
        print("Exiting program....")
        loop = False
```

I hope my answer was sufficient and now you know, how to program the best calculator ever known to humanity :D